# Why does my laptop recognize my external DVD player that turns on, but not play any DVDs on it?

Tags: dvd

I bought a Lenovo BP40N external DVD player in 2015. Since May 2 2021, it stopped playing DVDs.

[Moderator, please approve this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyPpH.jpg).

I troubleshot  on two Windows 10 computers. When I plug in the USB cable for the BP40N  into a computer's USB port, I can hear the BP40N spinning and the BP40N's light turns green. Both computers automatically launch PowerDVD. All this proves that the computer recognizes the BP40N, and the BP40N is working electronically. But then nothing happens. The BP40N doesn't actually show up on "Devices and drives" under My Computer.

Before May 2021, after PowerDVD automatically launches, the BP40N would start playing automatically. The BP40N used to show up on "Devices and drives" under My Computer.

Comment: So the drive doesn’t get assigned a drive letter at all?

Comment: @Ramhound No it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optical drives not showing up in the Windows Explorer unfortunately is a common problem of Windows, and that since Windows 7, although i Windows 10 it happens way more often. Unfortunately there is no universal way to fix it, but with a little time and effort you may find a solution that works for you if this one doesn't.

What helps me almost every time when something hardware related does not work any longer, e.g fingerprint scanner or external cameras, and should work for a regular optical drive as well is

1. Open Device Manager
2. Select View > Show hidden devices
3. Search for your DVD Drive
4. Right click on it and select update drivers
5. Reboot your PC

Usually after this procedure, even if no new driver is found and the older one stays in use, the device works again. If it doesn't there is one more drastical step you can take:
After you found the DVD Drive,
select instead

4. Uninstall
5. Reboot your PC
6. Open Device Manager again
7. In the top menu click on Scan for hardware changes, this should bring back up your DVD Drive
8. Wait for the driver installation to finish
9. If the drive does not show up in the Windows Explorer directly afterwards, reboot another time.

---

This is what helps me, but of course I don't know your setup, so maybe this doesn't work for you. If it doesn't work, you may look into [this](https://windowsreport.com/dvd-drive-windows-10/) article if something of these suggestions work for you.